# Select a row to search in for a string, return whole column and copy it to other sheet

Tags: vba, excel

Im facing a problem makeing a loop through row7 for example and returning the Row(which i know, its 7) + Column and copy entire column.

Lets say i need to find "DG" on row 7, i used to search like that:

```
Dim Found As Range, LastRow As Long
Set Found = Rows(7).Find(What:=value1, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not Found Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = Found.Address
            MsgBox "found" & firstAddress
        Do

    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, Found.Column).End(xlUp).Row
```

Then hardcoded with SwitchCase :| to return the column to to copy...

I cant post the whole code coz its switch cased from A to Z. The code works, but it is not clear :( i need it dynamic.

**Goal:**
Specify the row then search on each column ON THAT row only for a value. If found, copy the entire column to another sheet, then loop again (something like .nextRight or something, i know its a parameter) from the column that value was found (like row 7, column 5 or E) to right for the value im looking for untill the value isnt found on that row anymore. The Columns copyed should be placed 1 after another.

I used to code it like so :

```
Set Found = .FindNext(Found)
        Loop While Not Found Is Nothing And Found.Address <> firstAddress
```

// for the loop

```
Set destination = Sheets("Sheet1")
    emptyColumn = destination.Cells(7, destination.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
    MsgBox "empty coloana" & emptyColumn

    If emptyColumn > 1 Then
        emptyColumn = emptyColumn
    End If
```

// for the path that entire column found is placed on another sheet. This code aint working well ... it start with column B all the time, then C, D and so on... But why aint start with column A?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it is starting at the beginning, but if you are looking at every cell in a sheet, why iterate through every row when you can just iterate through every cell? This runs pretty quick and should work how you want it to.

```
Sub main()
    For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells
        If cell <> "" Then
            MsgBox (cell.Row & ":" & cell.Column)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I provided the MsgBox to show the row/column details you can pull from `ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells` object.

Comment: Yeah, i know! thanks for your answer but, i need to iterate through every cell of row 7 till the value inserted on a input pop-up is found. After that copy the entire column to another sheet and continue iterating till nothing found on that row.

Comment: Do you only care about Row 7? Do you have specific rows you care about, others you do not?

Comment: Yeap, i care only about the rows, coz i might have on row 5 the value i have on row 7 too, but i want to find the value on row 7 and copy the whole column. Thats the thing i cant understand... why is so hard to select a range .... i used to call findnext for loop and now it doesnt work anymoire ... im stuck

Comment: What I want you to see in my example is that this searches every row and can provide you with the row in which the value is found. Now, you can change up 'If cell <> "" Then' to something like 'If INSTR(cell , "NG")>0 then' and use 'cell.row' and get the specific row. I'm not certain why this would not work for you? if you have specific rows you are needing to hunt through, you can add an array and make sure the row that met the condition is a valid row. Please also do know this checks every cell in the spreadsheet not the total contents of the row.